# sql relationship

Tags: sql

I created 3 tables ,
Employee,
Appointment,
Company.

The relationships are :

1)Employee have a fk of companyId.

2)Appointment have a fk of employeeId.

**Why sql create new relationship between company and appointment ?**

The tables :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Appointment] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Appointment] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [CompanyId] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Employee] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Company] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Appointment] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Appointment_dbo.Employee_EmployeeId] FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([Id])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Employee_dbo.Company_CompanyId] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Company] ([Id])
```

Picture of sql view with the problem 
: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What version of SQL are you using? I tried to reproduce it on my machine but it didn't created the foreign key between company and appointment.

[image: Screenshot]

What you can do is, drop the tables and execute your script again. Give it a try

Comment: I try it on sql server 2012,2014,2016.

Comment: Ok try to recreate these tables, there's nothing wrong with the script you have provided.

Comment: I try it again with new database and got the same result :/ .

Comment: Version :

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      13.0.16100.1
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.3.9600.17415
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.18538
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.9600